# batch-Goto Loop if program found

Tags: loops, batch-file, goto

For the life of me I can't figure out why I can't echo test exit with this simple batch script using GOTO. The path exists. This should be VERY simple, but something missing. If I run this script I should echo "Test Exit", but I'm getting "Test Install" even if the path exists. Any Help?

```
@echo off

:TestInstall
Echo Test Install

pause

IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe" (
    GOTO TestExit
    )ELSE{
    GOTO TestInstall
    }

:TestExit
Echo Test Exit

pause
```

Comment: What makes you think you can mix and match parentheses with curly braces?  If you read the help for the `IF` command it will show you exactly how the syntax is used when you need to use the `ELSE` clause.

Comment: @Squashman nothing. It was an error on my part

Answer (score 1):

```
)ELSE{
GOTO TestInstall
}
```

Huh? Why do you use different parantheses/brackets? Also batch is quite picky about spaces - there have to be one before and after `else`:

```
) ELSE (
GOTO TestInstall
)
```

Comment: Error on my behalf. Didn't see the different brackets

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
@echo off

:install
echo install
pause

IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe" (
  goto install
) ELSE (
  goto exit
)

:exit
echo exit
pause
```

Well, you have `)ELSE{`which is not correct, it must be translated to `) ELSE (` and close with a parenthesis and not a curly brace. Also do forget to put the spaces.

Be aware  though that if the file doesn't exists you'll have an infinite loop running between the `:install` and the `goto install` instructions.

Moreover, at the beginning of your script, because the `:install` label is right in the top, it'll run the `install` part before doing any check.

You should move the install part under the if statement if you don't want this to happen.